# Replacing part of string in Array PHP

Tags: php, arrays, preg-replace

I have JSON response that looks like this

```
(
  [0] => stdClass Object

     (
       [default] => false
       [loc] => http://somethingirrelevant.lol
       [temp] => '100'
     )

)
```

What i am looking to accomplish change the url in `[LOC]` to `https`

I tried using :

```
$array = preg_replace('http','https' $array);
```

but that completly breaks array!

Answer (score 1):

You have an array of an object. Array key `0` is an object with a `loc` property, and you can use `str_replace()` here:

```
  $array[0]->loc = str_replace('http://', 'https://', $array[0]->loc);
//$array[0]->loc = preg_replace('#http://#', 'https://', $array[0]->loc);
```

If you decode as an array:

```
  $array = json_decode($json, true);
```

Then:

```
  $array[0]['loc'] = str_replace('http://', 'https://', $array[0]['loc']);
```

Comment: Not just that, regex must be enclosed between delimiters ;)

Comment: I would add you should use wordboundary to avoid replacing `https` with `httpss`

Comment: @Toto Thanks! Last time I post when I'm trying to leave for lunch.

Answer (score 0):

You can't simply call the Array, what you can do is iterate throught it and replace every value with the key `loc`:

```
foreach($array AS $key=>$value) {
    if(isset($value['LOC'])) {
         $array[$key]['LOC'] = preg_replace('http','https', $array);
    }
}
```

You can cast your array into a regular array instead of an object :

```
if(!is_array($array)) $array = (array)array;
```

Comment: actually, the syntax error was in the original code i copied, But i should have noticed it. Thanks.